# How to get selections each day using Flask APScheduler?

Tags: python, flask, apscheduler

I want my web app to return 5 daily highlights for review. And I should return the same highlights on the same day. I am working on it for 2-3 days but nothing seem to be working I tried using schedule and python-crontab but it is not working.

Here is the code

**app.**init**.py**

```
# To show daily highlights
@app.route('/daily')
@login_required
def today():
    today = date.today()
    highlights = get_daily_highlights()
    
    return render_template('today.html', highlights=highlights, today=today.strftime("%b %d, %Y"))
```

**Method**

```
# Filter 5 random highlights from the database
def get_daily_highlights():
    highlights = Highlight.query.filter(
        Highlight.user_id == current_user.id).order_by(func.random()).limit(5).all()
    return highlights
```

Comment: You're talking about worker processes calculating highlights, but you show code about visualising them Do you have a function that calculates the highlights, but you only want to schedule it? Or do you need help calculating them as well?

Comment: @RubenHelsloot Everything is working fine. I just want to schedule the method so that for each day it should return 5 highlights(5 highlights for each day). For now it is just returning 5 random highlights each time i visit the route /daily.

Comment: But the method is an API call, do you want to automatically call the API each day?